# error en conteo de puntaje de un test javascript

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, condiciones, onclick, contador

mi codigo no funciona, deberia retornar una alerta con el puntaje obtenido en la trivia,(lo cual se logra a través de la funcion puntajeculturageneral situada mas abajo) sin embargo al apretar el boton "puntaje total" (el cual deberia accionar la funcion al ser cliqueada) nada sucede, no arroja un error que imposibilite el codigo, pero el boton no reacciona al click. adjunto el extracto de mi codigo html y javascript

```
<body id= "contenidoTrivia">
   
<h2 id= "izquierda">
Lee atentamente las siguientes preguntas y marca la alternativa correcta:
  </h2>
    <center>
    <h1>
    1. ¿Quién diseñó la cúpula de la catedral de Florencia?:
    </h1>
    <p><br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa" value="Leonardo Da Vinci"> Leonardo Da Vinci<br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa" id = "correcta1" value="Filippo Brunelleschi"> Filippo Brunelleschi<br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa" value="Leon Battista Alberti">Leon Battista Alberti<br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa" value="Miguel Angel Buonarroti">Miguel Angel Buonarroti
    </p>
      <p><input type="submit" id= "respuesta1" value="Responder y ver resultados"></p>

      <h1>
    2. ¿En que año comenzó la revolución francesa?:
    </h1>
    <p><br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa" value="1799"> 1799<br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa" value="1899"> 1899<br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa" id= "correcta2" value="1789">1789<br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa" value="1659">1659
    </p>
      <p><input type="submit" id= "respuesta2" value="Responder y ver resultados"></p>
 <h1>
    3. ¿Qué acontecimiento histórico sucedió el 12 de Octubre de 1492?:
    </h1>
    <p><br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa" value="Nació el universo"> Nació el universo<br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa" value="Humano llega a la luna"> Humano llega a la luna<br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa" id = "correcta3" value="Descubrimiento de América">Descubrimiento de América<br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa" value="Descubrimiento de Chile">Descubrimiento de Chile
    </p>
      <p><input type="submit" id= "respuesta3" value="Responder y ver resultados"></p>
      <button id="puntajegeneral">puntaje total</button>
    <button onclick="location.href='index.html'">Volver a jugar</button>
    </center>
 
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

//javascript

```
function puntajeculturageneral() {

var p1, p2, p3, nota;


if (document.getElementById('correcta1').checked==true) {p1=1}

else {p1=0}

if (document.getElementById('correcta2').checked==true) {p2=1}

else {p2=0}

if (document.getElementById('correcta3').checked==true) {p3=1}

else {p3=0}

nota=p1+p2+p3;

alert(" obtuviste " + nota + "aciertos");

}
document.getElementById("puntajegeneral").onclick = function (){
    puntajeculturageneral();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo tienes al usar el mismo `name` para todos los radio button. Usa un `name` diferente por cada grupo y funciona.

```js
function puntajeculturageneral() {

var p1, p2, p3, nota;


if (document.getElementById('correcta1').checked==true) {
p1=1

}

else {p1=0}

if (document.getElementById('correcta2').checked==true) {p2=1}

else {p2=0}

if (document.getElementById('correcta3').checked==true) {p3=1}

else {p3=0}

nota=p1+p2+p3;

alert(" obtuviste " + nota + "aciertos");

}
document.getElementById("puntajegeneral").onclick = function (){
    puntajeculturageneral();
}
```

```html
<body id= "contenidoTrivia">
   
<h2 id= "izquierda">
Lee atentamente las siguientes preguntas y marca la alternativa correcta:
  </h2>
    <center>
    <h1>
    1. ¿Quién diseñó la cúpula de la catedral de Florencia?:
    </h1>
    <p><br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa" value="Leonardo Da Vinci"> Leonardo Da Vinci<br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa" id = "correcta1" value="Filippo Brunelleschi"> Filippo Brunelleschi<br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa" value="Leon Battista Alberti">Leon Battista Alberti<br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa" value="Miguel Angel Buonarroti">Miguel Angel Buonarroti
    </p>
      <p><input type="submit" id= "respuesta1" value="Responder y ver resultados"></p>

      <h1>
    2. ¿En que año comenzó la revolución francesa?:
    </h1>
    <p><br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa1" value="1799"> 1799<br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa1" value="1899"> 1899<br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa1" id= "correcta2" value="1789">1789<br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa1" value="1659">1659
    </p>
      <p><input type="submit" id= "respuesta2" value="Responder y ver resultados"></p>
 <h1>
    3. ¿Qué acontecimiento histórico sucedió el 12 de Octubre de 1492?:
    </h1>
    <p><br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa2" value="Nació el universo"> Nació el universo<br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa2" value="Humano llega a la luna"> Humano llega a la luna<br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa2" id = "correcta3" value="Descubrimiento de América">Descubrimiento de América<br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa2" value="Descubrimiento de Chile">Descubrimiento de Chile
    </p>
      <p><input type="submit" id= "respuesta3" value="Responder y ver resultados"></p>
      <button id="puntajegeneral">puntaje total</button>
    <button onclick="location.href='index.html'">Volver a jugar</button>
    </center>
 
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: pero no entiendo que tiene que ver el name si no los estaba usando, pues obtengo la info a traves de los id si no me equivoco, agradeceria tu aclaracion, muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Cierto me salté al siguiente problema. Si el botón no reacciona a nada entonces prueba que la referencia al archivo `script.js` esté correcta. Porque el código funciona.